# Bring data from Form 1 to other forms

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I've tried the methods from

[Getting values from two or more forms C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498308/getting-values-from-two-or-more-forms-c-sharp)
[Sharing a variable between two winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552169/sharing-a-variable-between-two-winforms)
[Get value from parentform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675872/get-value-from-parentform?rq=1)
and
[passing username to form but username returns null c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504210/passing-username-to-form-but-username-returns-null-c-sharp?rq=1)

But i couldnt get mine to work as i will get some random argument error.

[image: the two forms]
From the picture , i just want the username on Login form to be put into label1 on User form.

But also be able for other forms to use later as well.

Can someone help with this?

Login Form Code :

```
public partial class Login : Form
    {
        UserForm _userform = new UserForm();
        Admin _Adminform = new Admin();

        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void loginscs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string userNameText = txtUser.Text;
                string passwordText = txtPass.Text;
                string isAdmin = "yes";
                string isNotAdmin = "no";
                if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUser.Text)) && !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPass.Text)))
                {
                    SqlConnection SCScon = new SqlConnection();
                    SCScon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=PEWPEWDIEPIE\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ISNULL(SCSID, '') AS SCSID, ISNULL(SCSPass,'') AS SCSPass, ISNULL(isAdmin,'') AS isAdmin FROM SCSID WHERE SCSID='" + txtUser.Text + "' and SCSPass='" + txtPass.Text + "'", SCScon);
                    SCScon.Open();
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (dr.Read())
                    {
                        if (this.CompareStrings(dr["SCSID"].ToString(), txtUser.Text) &&
                            this.CompareStrings(dr["SCSPass"].ToString(), txtPass.Text) &&
                            this.CompareStrings(dr["isAdmin"].ToString(), isAdmin))
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Hello " + txtUser.Text, "Admin", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                            _Adminform.Show();
                            this.Hide();
                        }
                        else if (this.CompareStrings(dr["SCSID"].ToString(), txtUser.Text) &&
                            this.CompareStrings(dr["SCSPass"].ToString(), txtPass.Text) &&
                            this.CompareStrings(dr["isAdmin"].ToString(), isNotAdmin))
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + txtUser.Text, "User");
                            _userform.Show();
                            this.Hide();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Wrong ID/Pass");
                    }
                    SCScon.Close();
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error2" + ex);
            }
        }

        private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private bool CompareStrings(string string1, string string2)
        {
            return String.Compare(string1, string2, true, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == 0 ? true : false;
        }
    }
```

===========================

Here , i've tried this , but this , did not work..

[image: that thing]

Comment: #Grant Winney @Grant Winney -  Why do i get a duplicate when the date is 4 years difference , as well as the coding method as well as the problem.

The title might almost be the same , but the problem is different. I have also provided other links above.

Please check before marking as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Create a consturctor for the second form and in it's creation (calling `new Form2(...)`) - send as parameters the user name an / or the password.

Comment: i have no idea how to do that.. Sorry , i have low basic , but i do understand the code.. mind teaching me? i just dont get the terms.. like , a constructor.. have no idea what is that.

Comment: A constructor is like a factory that creates your class. You can have a deafult parameter-less constructor that is called like this: Form F1 = new From(). Or, you can create a constructor of your own - it's an overload (try reading about it). If you create a new constructor and give it 2 string params for example you can call the form like this: Form2 F2 = New Form2(word1,word2);

Comment: ah.. okay.. so my username from first form is txtUser , so in UserForm , i create a UserForm F2 = new UserForm(txtUser.Text);? like this?

Comment: but how do i make txtUser from LoginForm detectable in UserForm?

Comment: You need to add a method to the UserForm. like this: pubilc UserForm (string userName, string Passowrd) { some code...}. Try reading in the net about overloading and constructor as well.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/oek52H3.png here... i got this..

Answer (score 0):

You can add constructor that get parameters to UserForm and give some object that in the constructor will have the object.

you also can add getter/setter in the Userform and update the information that you want to pass.

Comment: i have no idea how to do that.. 

Sorry , i have low basic , but i do understand the code..

i just dont get the terms.. like , a constructor.. have no idea what is that..

mind teaching me?

Answer (score 0):

You can, for example, simply use a property:

**Form2:**

```
public string UserText { get; set;}

...

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter keyword to search");
    }
    else 
    {
        UserText = textBox1.Text; // set the Text
    }
```

**Form1:**

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.ShowDialog();   //open form2-search form  

    string text = from2.UserText; get the Text

    ....
```

[This Answer is stated by Dominic Kexel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791071/get-user-input-in-form2-and-display-data-in-form1-in-c-sharp)
Hope this help

Comment: oh come on.. look at my code first..

Comment: here.. 

http://i.imgur.com/oek52H3.png

Comment: Yes what I'm saying, just store the textbox value in one property and pass that value as stated above

Comment: I am sorry , but i am a specific kind of person.

So let me get this straight. in my LoginForm , i do ''public string UserText { get; set; }'' , i put that on Class Level. Am i correct now? futhermore , i put ''UserText = txtUser.Text;'' on my Login button.. is that correct?

Comment: Yes proceed further. else give your code details fully then i can suggest you

Comment: and in my User form , where do i put this? ''Login Form1 = new Login();" and ''string text = Login.UserText;" , as i dont want to click any button on my User Form for the Username to be shown on the Label1. (refer picture on the question)

Comment: In your button click just call the property as you said

Comment: the textbox in LoginForm is named ''txtUser'' , so in context , it is then txtUser.Text.

i want it to show on the Label1 on UserForm.

Comment: Login Form1 = new Login(); Login.ShowDialog(); Label1.Text = Login.UserText;

Comment: i got this error.. http://i.imgur.com/tWe11OT.png

Comment: now where do i put this? Login Form1 = new Login(); Login.ShowDialog(); string text = Login.UserText;

Comment: which button? on the userForm or the loginform?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44086/discussion-between-mohd-nasrul-iwan-fajaruddin-and-vignesh-kumar)